# SSRS count only visible group headers (footers)

Tags: reporting-services

I have records like these:
`GR_ID, “debit”, “credit”, “balance”`

Example:

`1, 100.00, 0.00, 100.00`
`1, 200.00, 50.00, 150.00`
`1, 0.00, 50.00, -50.00`
`2, 300.00, 0.00, 300.00`
`2, 0.00, 300.00, -300.00`
`3, 200.00, 0.00, 200.00`
`3, 100.00, 200.00, -100.00`

I need to print only group totals but only if group total for “balance”<>0.00 and I need to count them.
The group with `GR_ID=2` should not be visible because the total `balance=0` and result look like this:

`1, 300.00, 100.00, 200.00`
`3, 300.00, 200.00, 100.00`

Count: **2** : Total Debit: 600.00, Total Credit: 300.00; Total Balance: 300.00

I cannot find a way to get that `COUNT` in SSRS.
I know I can do it by filtering records using SQL and using SSRS `CountDistinct()` function, but I’m interested in an SSRS solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution! The "Count" field in the "TOTALS" row should be calculated using: =CountDistinct(iif(Sum(Fields!Balance.Value, "Gr_ID")=0,nothing,Fields!Gr_ID.Value))

Answer (score 0):

I tried various methods and the only way I was able to get it to work was with a Count of Report Items in the Header for the GR_ID cell in the table.

[image]

```
=COUNT(ReportItems!GR_ID.Value)
```

[image]

I thought I could get it in the table by grouping and using the same grouping filter but I was still getting 3 instead of two. Apparently it counts BEFORE the filter is applied.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work for me. I created a textbox with expression =COUNT(ReportItems!GR_ID.Value) and put it on Page Footer, result =1. When I put it on Page Header, the result=0. Could you please give me more details?

Comment: Hmm - Are you sure it's the name of the text box in the table that can be either 1 or 3 in your example. I added pics to the answer to see if you have the wrong text box.

Comment: Sorry, but it's still not clear for me. I would like to put my images here but I don't know how. And here are additional details: - the "balance" is calculated field/column; Details row is hidden, so only Group footers with GR_ID and Sum(Fields!Debit.Value), Sum(Fields!Creit.Value), Sum(Fields!Balance.Value) are printing. And Group footer has conditional visibility (hidden if: =Sum(Fields!Balance.Value)=0).

Comment: I just repeated you result and it works... But it prints the count for the Page, but not a total count.:( So it looks like Report Builder can't do it!

Comment: Finally found the solution! The "Count" field in the "TOTALS" row should be calculated using: =CountDistinct(iif(Sum(Fields!Balance.Value, "Gr_ID")=0,nothing,Fields!Gr_ID.Value))